# Unable to connect to DB2 database server over sec port using SSL from windows ODBC DSN client machine

Tags: security, ssl, db2, odbc, dsn

I am trying to connect DB2 database servers over secure port using SSL from system ODBC DSN client machine. But I am getting below error

I am using correct DB2 server IP and SSL port and connecting Z/OS Db2.

```
 Error: SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol
    being used: "SSL".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where
    the error was detected: "".  Communication function detecting the error:
    "sqlccSSLSocketSetup".  Protocol specific error code(s): "420", "*", "*".
    SQLSTATE=08001
```

The steps I have done:

1. Created Keystore .kdb file along with stash file .sth file.
2. Added the certificate to Keystore and it is having Root cert,
   Intermediate certificate and personal certificate
3. ODBC configurations

   [ODBC Security options selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CZBq.png)
   [ODC advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j923l.png)
   [ODBC TCPIP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14TaK.png)

Process followed to add the certificates to .KDB key store

1. Requested a certificate in the company portal.
2. Once it is approved downloaded it in .pfx format.
3. Created .kdb keystore using the below command
   gsk8capicmd  -keydb -create -db fullpath/test.kdb -stash -pw password
4. imported .pfx file into keystore using below command
   gsk8capicmd -cert -import -db fullpath/cert.pfx -target fullpath/test.kdb -target_stashed
5. added root certificate using below command
   gsk8capicmd -cert -add -db fullpath/test.kdb -stashed -file fullpath/root.cer -label rootlabel
6. added intermediate certificate using below command
   gsk8capicmd -cert -add -db fullpath/test.kdb -stashed -file fullpath/issuer.cer -label issuerlabel

db2cli config parameters.:

```
[TEST]
Security=SSL
Port=0000
Database=test
Hostname=0.0.0.0
PWD=xxxxx
UID=xxxx
```

db2dsdriver config parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<configuration>
<databases>
<database host="0.0.0.0" name="TEST" port="0000">
<parameter name="SecurityTransportMode" value="SSL"/>
<parameter name="SSLClientKeyStoredb" value="fullpath\test.kdb"/>
<parameter name="SSLClientKeystash" value="fullpath\test.sth"/>
</database>
</databases>

<dsncollection>
<dsn alias="testalias" host="0.0.0.0" name="TEST" port="0000"/>
</dsncollection>

</configuration>
```

Let me know if any additional details required in this regard which can hekp to identify and fix the issue.

db2 level command output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "32" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11010" with level identifier
"0201010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.0.1527", "s1606081100",
"DYN1606081100WIN32", and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".
```

db2level.exe & db2cli.exe are in same directory

db2dsdriver config parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<configuration>
<databases>
<database host="0.0.0.0" name="TEST" port="0000">
<parameter name="SecurityTransportMode" value="SSL"/>
<parameter name="SSLClientKeyStoredb" value="fullpath\test.kdb"/>
<parameter name="SSLClientKeystash" value="fullpath\test.sth"/>
</database>
</databases>

<dsncollection>
<dsn alias="testalias" host="0.0.0.0" name="TEST" port="0000"/>
</dsncollection>

</configuration>
```

Copied 3 SSL parameters to DSN stanza:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<configuration>
<databases>
<database host="0.0.0.0" name="TEST" port="0000">
<parameter name="SecurityTransportMode" value="SSL"/>
<parameter name="SSLClientKeyStoredb" value="fullpath\test.kdb"/>
<parameter name="SSLClientKeystash" value="fullpath\test.sth"/>
</database>
</databases>

<dsncollection>
<dsn alias="testalias" host="0.0.0.0" name="TEST" port="0000"/>
<parameter name="SecurityTransportMode" value="SSL"/>
<parameter name="SSLClientKeyStoredb" value="fullpath\test.kdb"/>
<parameter name="SSLClientKeystash" value="fullpath\test.sth"/>
</dsncollection>

</configuration>
```

Tried with copying only one parameter inside the DSN stanza as in below

```
<dsncollection>
<dsn alias="testalias" host="0.0.0.0" name="TEST" port="0000">
<parameter name="SecurityTransportMode" value="SSL"/>
</dsn
</dsncollection>
```

The output is: Validation completed but it is showing as duplicated - but still getting 420 error

```
[ Parameters used for the connection ]

Keywords                  Valid For     Value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATABASE                  CLI,.NET,ESQL TEST
HOSTNAME                  CLI,.NET,ESQL 0.0.0.0
PORT                      CLI,.NET,ESQL 0000
SECURITYTRANSPORTMODE     CLI,.NET      **DUPLICATE**
SSLCLIENTKEYSTOREDB       CLI,.NET,ESQL fullpath\client.kdb
SSLCLIENTKEYSTASH         CLI,.NET,ESQL fullpath\client.sth
```

I am not sure whether to directly connect to database on Z/OS or via gateway.

Comment: Additionally there may be more details about the error in the Db2-server *diagnostics* location. So you should look in there also. In your question you give no information about exactly how you are connecting, how you specify __which__ of the certificates.  This is a *programming* website, so you should show your code and whatever details are necessary to answer the question.

Comment: I have edited the question as suggested.I have provided the images in links to check the ODBC settings that i have selected. The intention is to use the server authentication.

Comment: In the ODBC DSN I am using userid and password to connect. db2cli validate is completed successfully.When i run this command getting 420 error. db2cli validate -dsn YOURDSN -connect -user XXX -passwd YYYY

Comment: Duplicate the __three__ ssl parameters to the DSN stanza (copied from the database stanza).   Retry the `db2cli validate -dsn XXX -user XXXX -passwd XXXXX`.

Comment: when i copied the 3 parameters into DSN stanza the validation is failed with error Message : Element 'parameter' is not valid for content model: '(dsn*|defaultdsn?)'

Comment: The `<parameter name...`  entries need to be inside the `<dsn alias` block, and that block must end with `</dsn>` .  Please also state in your question whether you are connecting *directly* to the database on Z/OS from your workstation, or whether you are going via a Db2-connect gateway server.

Comment: You should ask your Z-DBA if the connection is __direct__,  or  __indirect__ via a Db2-connect gateway. For a __direct__ connection, ask the Z-DBA for the diagnostics associated with the connection attempt (i.e. why the Z subsystem is rejecting the connection).  For an __indirect__ connection via a Db2-connect gateway, the db2diag.log on the gateway may have more details so ask the gateway admin for help to see what's in its db2diag.log file for your failed connections.

Comment: Thank you.I shall check with DBA and post the response back here.

Comment: You can also try a different  approach of using parameter SSLSERVERCERTIFICATE inside both the DSN stanza and database stanza, with value = fully qualified path to the root-certificate, instead of the two keywords for keystore and stash. See Knowledge Center for details. The  certificate has to be in correct format, so format conversion might be needed.